Cannot create an open stack instance
I configure my environment with 2 controller 3 computer nodes in an OpenStack Wallaby Ubuntu 20.04.5 environment, and eventually I can't create an instance with an error when creating an instance on the Horizon dashboard. I initially tried with Synder Volume 3, but it got the same result, so I try to proceed with Volume 2. Where do I check? Below is a log of what I tried.

openstack endpoint list | grep cinder

| -1496ae412a6545c0b61ae4756fe7da9e- | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3     | True    | admin     | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/%(project_id)s |
| -30e325b00a034f2cb3209511ca1ca0a-9 | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3     | True    | public    | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/%(project_id)s |
| -c0e35cf99af24f3580a24d205d71760e- | RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2     | True    | admin     | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/%(project_id)s |
| -d148ec19f20d4d249daffc1a9ecde94d- | RegionOne | cinderv3     | volumev3     | True    | internal  | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/%(project_id)s |
| -e51873cfa0c345edabeecbbf59002123-| RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2     | True    | internal  | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/%(project_id)s |
| -ec2ec3316c3e4b5ba3dadd2982eee18f- | RegionOne | cinderv2     | volumev2     | True    | public    | http://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/%(project_id)s |

cacalog list

cinderv2  | volumev2  | RegionOne                                                                    admin: ://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a    |
RegionOne              internal: ://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a |
RegionOne                    public: ://192.168.20.109:18776/v2/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a   |
cinderv3  | volumev3  | RegionOne                                                                   admin: ://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a
RegionOne                                                  |public:enter image description here://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a|RegionOne                                                                   internal: ://192.168.20.109:18776/v3/0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a

/var/log/nova/nova-compute.log

2024-04-17 09:29:36.185 518143 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-bf171821-43a6-400b-8d81-eca73978660b 9842918447bb4bc58e2e99a1540c65d2 0a7b7110b63c4fc2895c66b65cb38a9a - default default] [instance: f0ba3861-c16a-4322-851c-eb211c6a5f7f] Build of instance f0ba3861-c16a-4322-851c-eb211c6a5f7f aborted: internalURL endpoint for volumev2 service named cinder in RegionOne region not found: nova.exception.BuildAbortException: Build of instance f0ba3861-c16a-4322-851c-eb211c6a5f7f aborted: internalURL endpoint for volumev2 service named cinder in RegionOne region not found
2024-04-17 09:29:37.329 518143 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-bf171821-43a6-400b-8d81-eca73978660b 9842918447bb4bc58e2a - default default] [instance f0ba3861-c16a-4322-851c-eb211c] Took 0.45 seconds to deallocate network for instance.
